# Typical text files present on all (most) GNU/Linux systems?

Tags: files, standard

I may need to develop some short snippets/examples involving reading text files; so I thought - why not use some files that are typically present on all (and since I sense "all" may be a stretch, then "most" is fine) Linux "vanilla" systems/distros? (primarily interested in Linux here)

The only one I can think of for now is `/etc/fstab` - however, it should be owned by `root`, so I'm not sure whether that will interfere with my snippets later on - I'd like an average user to at least be able to read them  (although, `fstab`'s permissions are `-rw-r--r--`, so I don't think read-only would be a problem; for instance, `cat /etc/fstab` works fine under my regular username). Another reason why I wouldn't like to use it, is because it contains potentially sensitive information...

In any case, I was wondering - are there any other text-files that could be considered "standard" in typical GNU/Linux systems, that I could use for this purpose? (basically, something like [example.com](http://example.com/), but on your local filesystem)

Comment: There are many such files, probably. But why not create your own example files? One file that is commonly available in any system that uses a bash shell, as most Linux-based Os's do, is `.bashrc`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @FaheemMitha - I was precisely trying to avoid creating own example files.. `.bashrc` looks like a good suggestion, though ... Cheers!

Comment: A surprising number of system files are world readable.  I suppose this fits in with the idea that ["security through obscurity"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) (eg., by concealing configuration details) is not worth bothering with too much.

Comment: @goldilocks Debian's take (in http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/securing-debian-howto/ch12.en.html). "The current policy regarding log files and configuration files is that they are world readable unless they provide sensitive information." I'm too lazy to see if policy says anything specific about this.

Answer (score 3):

This is tricky, because while many text files may be present in most Linux systems, they are not necessarily guaranteed to be in the same place. @tintifaxx's `/proc` answer is good since this will work on all but the oldest/most oddly configured kerneks.

That said, here are some fairly safe bets in `/etc`

```
/etc/fstab
/etc/group
/etc/hosts
/etc/hostname
/etc/localtime
/etc/passwd
```

Also `/proc/mounts` is a good one because calling `mount` does very minimal formatting on this and so could be a good short snippet.

#### Edit

If you are looking for files available in the user's home directory, you can do:

```
graeme@graeme:~$ ls -a /etc/skel
.  ..  .bash_logout  .bashrc  .profile
```

These files are copied in to the user's home when the account is created, so you can expect them to be there for every user on the system. `.profile` is more ubiquitous than bash. The problem with these files though is that if they are written to by accident, this could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Graeme - I also mentioned in other comments: pretty much all in `/etc` is owned by `root` (even if it is world readable), and pretty much all in `/proc` has an actual file size 0 (even if it produces content upon, say, `cat`), and I've seen problems with that before (maybe APIs that seek to end of file before reading); and I'd like to avoid these possible stumbling blocks... Good to have a nice list of some other `/etc` candidates though - cheers!

Comment: Yeah, saw your comment about `/proc` just after I posted this, didn't know about that. I would say `/etc` is better because it is not writeable by normal users, as changing any of these common files is potentially problematic.

Answer (score 2):

when it's only about read-only you could try some "virtual" files in the proc filesystem, e.g */proc/cpuinfo*, */proc/filesystems* or */proc/meminfo*.
They should be readable by anyone in general.
They're also nice to parse and to extract useful information.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer @tintifaxx - however, I think all of the files in `/proc` report a file size of 0; and now I remember I actually think I tried them once long ago (cannot remember exactly in what context or with what program, unfortunately); and whatever program I was using failed, I think it was because if was trying to `seek` to the end of file first... so I'd still appreciate a suggestion for a "proper" text file. Good to keep this in mind though - cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Unix-like systems running the bash shell by default, like all "mainstream" Linux-based operating systems do, to my knowledge, generally ship with a non-empty `.bashrc` template which is placed by default in any users home directory. This by default world readable, but in any case is always readable by that user.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @FaheemMitha - the only thing I sort of don't like is that there can be many `.bashrc` in the system, and so I cannot use a single absolute path, but I have to resolve via `~/.bashrc` (and some programs may choke on `~`); but at least every user should have one, and it's good they're non-empty... If nothing else comes along, I'll eventually accept this answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Most systems also have a dictionary, `/usr/share/dict/linux.words`

This should give you a list of all text files on your system:

```
find / -type f -exec file {} + 2>/dev/null| grep ASCII
```

Comment: Many thanks for that @Ketan - unfortunately, my Ubuntu 11.04 reports: "ls: cannot access /usr/share/dict/linux.words: No such file or directory"; cheers!

Comment: On Ubuntu, you'll probably need to install `wordlist` package. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Words_(Unix) `sudo apt-get install wamerican` works on my `12.04`

Comment: Thanks for that, @Ketan - good to know; but I would have preferred a file that sort of "exists" without installing extra packages... Cheers!

Comment: I updated my answer with a command that will hopefully help.

Comment: @sdaau You're likely to have other word lists in `/usr/share/dict`. But Ubuntu doesn't ship a word list called `linux.words`.